# MySQL JDBC connection

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

I am developing a plain JSP webpage where I have to take feedback from clients and store in my MYSQL database.

While running on localhost apache server database connection runs fine but after hosting the page at EATJ.com database is not updated as expected so please can I get help with below code?

code:

```
<body>
 <%@page import="java.sql.*"%>

 <%
 String name=request.getParameter("name");
String email=request.getParameter("email");
String comment=request.getParameter("comment");
try{
String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pizza"; 

ResultSet rs=null;
Connection con= null; 
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance(); 
con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "prakashd22", "*******");
Statement st = con.createStatement();
String sql = ("INSERT INTO feedback VALUES ('" + name + "','" + email + "','"+ comment +"') ");
st.executeUpdate(sql);
rs.close();
st.close();
con.close();
}
catch(Exception e){out.print(e);}
%>
<jsp:include page="feed.jsp" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please give more details on the error, maybe a stack trace? Off the top of my head, the Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver") might crash if your app is missing the mysqlj driver (jar file)

Comment: This line:
    String sql = ("INSERT INTO feedback VALUES ('" + name + "','" + email + "','"+ comment +"') ");
is incorrect java Syntax the brackets around are not needed, remove them.
Furthermore you should not use this code in any production website, as it is vulnerable to SQL Injection.
Please read something about design patterns in web applications. eg. MVC - Model View Controller. And print the exception stacktrace or you wont get any error message..

Comment: also where is your database deployed. Do you use the correct connectionURL when you deploy? Is the port to the database open?

Comment: its running without exception but whwn i refresh and read my database table it doesnt show anything added recently.I have installed MYSQL 5.0 drver correctly.

Comment: are you sure there is no exception? Your catch block is empty? May be you swallow the exception?

Comment: @burna yes i know but this is my high school report so i have not used any servlets or mvc models

Comment: try to manually commit transaction `con.commit()` after insert in db, just in case autocommit was set to false. And use parameters, your insert is vulnerable to SQL Injection!

Comment: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /page/feedcode.jsp at line 22

19: 
20: Connection con= null; 
21: Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance(); 
22: con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "prakashd22", "*******");
23: Statement st = con.createStatement();
24: String sql = ("INSERT INTO feedback VALUES ('" + name + "','" + email + "','"+ comment +"') ");
25: st.executeUpdate(sql);

Answer (score 0):

The **null ResultSet object** appears to be in the way while you are doing an update statement

```
rs.close();
```

keep their code separate is wiser.

Answer (score 0):

Check for the following things
1) check whether `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` is present

2) `String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pizza"` whether the database is present at the local machine

3) If The database is on the remote server you might want to `GRANT` permissions to access this database http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html

And please the stack trace!! Hope this helps!

Comment: i am getting this exception now:- org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.mysql.jdbc.StringUtils